# Выражения эквивалентны?

Tags: java

Есть созданный объект "Class" со ссылкой на него: "Class crntClass". 
Выражения:

```
crntClass==Object.class;
```

и

```
crntClass==Class.forName("Object");
```

эквиваленты или интерпретатор про100 меня не недолюбливает? 
**Заранее спасибо!**

Comment: У меня Class.forName("Object"); вообще java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Object выдает.

Comment: Точно, спс. Забыл прописать имя пакета перед ним. Правильно будет так: "java.lang.Object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выражения эквивалентны. Ошибка была в том, что не указано полное имя класса как строка-параметр метода forName(), объекта Class. Спасибо аvp за подсказку!